# ruby on rails getting a 2-way friend relationship in active record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Im trying to figure out how to do a mutual 2-way relationship, that is:

```
user_id  friend_id
  1          2
  2          1
```

In above user 1 and user 2 would be friends if both `user_id = 1` has `friend_id = 2` and `friend_id = 2` has `user_id = 2` as there friend in a table. How to count all the 2-way mutual relations in ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is a [`has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :friends, :class_name => "User",
                                    :foreign_key => "this_user_id",
                                    :association_foreign_key => "other_user_id"
end
```

Example is from [§4.4.2.1](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_and_belongs_to_many-association_foreign_key).

Comment: I think in this case you should use a rich association with `has_many :through`. This way you could have a relationship status (like "friends", "request by user 1", "request by user 2").

Comment: @Ashitaka Indeed you can, and you can always (relatively seamlessly) transition from `has_and_belongs_to_many` to having a concrete join model in the future as well.

Answer (score 1):

Read the final chapter of Micheal Heartl Ruby on Rails Tutorial: Learn Rails by Example where he explains these kind of examples really well. There is a free online edition here.

https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users

Take a look at the final chapter. I hope it helps.

Comment: "Do not create a new table. Create a table…" isn't that contradictory?