# newbie : getting mutual likes and only if they are mutual with active record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, mutual-friendship

What would be a good way to get mutual likes ? where 2 users like each other ( as in a friendlist) and get only those users who have a mutual match?

```
user_id   | likes_id 
1           2                
2           1

Only get results where both of the users likes each other ( friendship )
```

I have tried some join's but can't really get it to work, is there a building AR feature to get the above results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to jexact's answer this is one way you can do this using AR:

```
Like.joins('join likes l on likes.user_id=l.likes_id and l.user_id=likes.likes_id')
```

or

```
Like.select('l.*').joins('join likes l on likes.user_id=l.likes_id and l.user_id=likes.likes_id')
```

An alternative (slower? but imho looks cleaner) way is to do this in your User model (NOT tested, but should give you an idea):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :likes
  has_many :friends, :through => :likes

  has_many :liked_by, :foreign_key => 'likes_id', :class_name => 'Like'
  has_many :followers, :through => :liked_by, :source => :user

  def mutually_likes?(user)
    self.friends.include?(user) && self.followers.include?(user)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're looking for:
[ruby on rails getting a 2-way friend relationship in active record?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671829/ruby-on-rails-getting-a-2-way-friend-relationship-in-active-record)

Alternatively you can try this:

```
SELECT     a.user_id
FROM       likes AS a
INNER JOIN likes AS b
ON         a.user_id=b.likes_id
AND        a.likes_id=b.user_id
```

Comment: how would one Execute this RAW SQL in Ruby on rails?

Answer (score 1):

http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association

this way you can create relations between users, like I used this exemple to create relations between  Media Companies and Companies hwo owns this Media (in my case), where a Media could be owned by a company A, and company A is owned by Company B and this is where you get the Self-Referential Association.

In your case is much simpler to implement this as you need users models.. for me it took more modifications to do.

Comment: Ok I see but that uses: User, Friendship. I just want to check if theres a Mutual relation in model Likes. Don't really understand how I could hook it up could you clarify it perhaps with the use of my single model "Like" ?thx

Comment: you can rename it, and the link too, rename it from "add friend" to "Like friend" or simple "Like", anyway this is a relation between 2 records of the same model Users, so you need to use self-referenctial-association

Comment: in my case I had Company model and a company can be in a relation with another company being as owner, so I used a relationship called companyship instead of friendship.. this is not a copy paste code but you can modify it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I made it with

```
 @groups = Like.select('l.*').joins('join likes l on likes.user_id=l.likes and   l.user_id=likes.likes')

  unless @groups.empty?
    @groups.each do |group|
      friendship = Friendship.create(user_id: group.user_id, friend_id: group.likes)
    end
  end
```

The abstraction in model is nicer I look into that later on