# Validation condition on friendships in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, conditional-statements, rails-activerecord

I am writing my social network. I use devise as an authentication system. I used Self-Referential Association in railscasts. I want to solve my little problem that, I let users see the others profile and use a link to add friend. But if you are friend add to friend does show  again. I asked similar questions but since now i could not make it.

My Friendship model :

```
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :friend_id
  belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User"
    validates :friend, :presence => true, :unless => :friend_is_self

    validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => [:friend_id]

    def friend_is_self
        user_id == friend_id ? false : true
    end
end
```

My Users model :

```
....  has_many :friendships
    has_many :friends, :through => :friendships
    has_many :inverse_friendships, :class_name => "Friendship", :foreign_key => "friend_id"
    has_many :inverse_friends, :through => :inverse_friendships, :source => :user
end
```

This is my show.html.erb(user)

```
<section>
      <h1><%= @user.username %> </h1>
 <% unless current_user == @user %>
 <%= link_to "Arkadaşlarıma Ekle", friendships_path(:friend_id => @user), :method => :post,class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <%end %>
      </section>.
```

I am sorry for the similar question but i cant find the correct `if friend?` condition for the add friend link.

Comment: There's a very similar question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294147/newbie-getting-mutual-likes-and-only-if-they-are-mutual-with-active-record/11299435#11299435]

Answer (score 0):

How about a class method in the `Friendship` model?

```
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...

  def self.friendship_exists?(user1, user2)
    Friendship.where("(user_id = ? AND friend_id = ?) OR (user_id = ? AND friend_id = ?)", user1.id, user2.id, user2.id, user1.id).size > 0
  end
end
```

Now your `link_to_if` can be

```
link_to_unless Friendship.friendship_exists?(current_user, @user) ...
```

Comment: `exists?` is already defined in `AR::Base` (http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveResource/Base/exists%3F/class), I'd rename the method (unless this is really your intent).